# Pass a function to a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

In jquery I can do the following

```
$('#test').click(function() {
 // some action;
});
```

How do i do this with Linq, I understood that are created a function on the fly with

```
data.Where(x => x.Equals(10))
```

How do I pass in or create on the fly a function to pass into this?

Comment: You're already doing it... `x => x.Equals(10)` *is* a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression you wrote there: `x => x.Equals(10)` is already an anonymous function taking one integer parameter and returning a boolean. But you could write more complex expressions of course:

```
var result = data.Where(x => 
{
    if (someCondition) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```